# wordpress shortcode how to filter according to a custom taxonomy?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, shortcode

I have created a custom post type (school) and a custom taxonomy (region) attached to it.
Everything works great except I want to create a shortcode that only get the school that belongs to a specific entry in that custom taxonomy.
That means when you will write the shortcode you will pass a region name, and only schools that belong to that region will return from the database.
I managed to use the shortcode, but not to filter according to the region.

This is my custon taxonomy:

```
                $taxonomies['regions'] = array(
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'query_var' => 'school_region',
                'rewrite' => array(
                    'slug' => 'schools/region'
                    ),
                    'labels' => array(
                        'name' => __('Region'),
                        'singular_name' => __('Region'),
                        'add_new' => __('Add New Region'),
                        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Region'),
                        'edit_item' => __('Edit Region'),
                        'new_item' => __('Add New Region'),
                        'view_item' => __('View Region'),
                        'search_items' => __('Search Regions'),
                        'not_found' => __('No Region Found'),
                        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Regions Found In Trash'),
                ),
            );
```

And this is my shortcode:

```
add_shortcode('rs_school',function($atts, $content=null){



$loop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'rs-school', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC', 
) );
//var_dump($loop);

if($loop->have_posts() ){ ?>

<ul class="related">
    <?php

    while ($loop->have_posts()) {
        $loop->the_post();
        //$meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), ''); 
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'regions' );
        var_dump($terms);
        if (in_array($theregion, $terms)){
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo get_the_title() ?></a>
        </li>



    <?php   
        }
    } ?>
   </ul>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <?php
}
```

});

How can I do that?

best regards

Answer (score 0):

so managed to work it out. so hopefully will help others:

i send the term id to the short code, and use it to fillter it:

```
$atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'region' => 15,
    ), $atts, 'rs_school' );
```

and then filter it like so:

```
    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'rs-school', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'date', // Purely optional - just for some ordering
    'order' => 'DESC', // Ditto
    'tax_query' => array( 
            array( 
                'taxonomy' => 'regions', //or tag or custom taxonomy
                'field' => 'id', 
                'terms' => $atts['region'] 
            ) 
        ) 
) );
```

hope it will help others.